# How can I use listview inside a scrollview in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, scrollview

This is the image I want in my application:

[image: This is the image I want in my application]

I tried using listview inside a scrollview but the problem is that I am not able to stretch listview to its full size. Can anyone tell me how can I do this??

Comment: `NestedScrollView` with `RecyclerView` is the best option.

Comment: do you have any examples.if so please share with me

Comment: No need for any tutorial. Just put `RecyclerView`  in `NestedScrollView`

Comment: it's bad idea to use one scroll inside another. Just add all the views into the ScrollView.

Comment: but i need tutorial

Comment: @VladMatvienko `RecyclerView` in `NestedScrollView` is not bad idea

Comment: @Piyush, it is not required at all in this place as I understood. Since it is designed to `Recycle views`, and it won't recycle anything in the case of this question.

Comment: @VladMatvienko There will always be some cases where you need to add nested scrolling. e.g. in profile there will be vertical scrolling to see full details and some horizontal list to view some of user's images. In that case nested scrolling is useful. That's why google introduces NestedScrollView to overcome this problem'

Comment: @Prag'sシ, that's right, but it's helpfull when you want to use 2 different-dimentional scrollings.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your recyclerview as below example :

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <!-- Some views-->


            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_bubhub_comment_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

You can use below properties in recyclerview if you need both layout to scroll. Otherwise it would work as single scrolling view. These properties allows `Recyclerview` to scroll inside `NestedScrollView`

```
app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```